# Tween move and changing direction

Tags: actionscript

I'm attempting to make a ball drop down on stage and then changing direction upon impact of another object. In this scenario the ball falls on a slide and suppose to roll down the slide to the bottom of the stage. however before it continue down the slide, it jumps to another location and then slides down. I can't put my finger on the problem. Also I want it to stop at the bottom left and not the center. Can you help me figuring it out?

Below is the code and a Gif that demonstrate the problem. I'm using `BitmapData hitTest` event listener to generate the impact effect. and I'm using `localToGlobal` variable to find the location of the ball to use in the tween for changing direction.

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

var blueClip: objct2 = new objct2();
addChild(blueClip);
//blueClip.x = 196;
//blueClip.y = 73;

var tweenY: Tween = new Tween(blueClip, "y", Regular.easeIn, 73, 0, 0, false);
var tweenX: Tween = new Tween(blueClip, "x", Strong.easeIn, 196, 0, 0, false);

var redRect: Rectangle = redClip.getBounds(this);
var redClipBmpData = new BitmapData(redRect.width, redRect.height, true, 1);
redClipBmpData.draw(redClip);


var blueRect: Rectangle = blueClip.getBounds(this);
var blueClipBmpData = new BitmapData(blueRect.width, blueRect.height, true, 1);
blueClipBmpData.draw(blueClip);

Button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event: MouseEvent): void {
  var tweenY: Tween = new Tween(blueClip, "y", Regular.easeIn, 100, 400, 1, true);

  addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
}

function enterFrame(e: Event): void {

  if (redClipBmpData.hitTest(new Point(redClip.x, redClip.y),
  255,
  blueClipBmpData,
  new Point(blueClip.x, blueClip.y),
  255
  )) {
  var yourMC: DisplayObject = blueClip;
  var point1: Point = yourMC.localToGlobal(new Point(yourMC.getRect(yourMC).x, yourMC.getRect(yourMC).y));
  var point2: Point = yourMC.localToGlobal(new Point(yourMC.getRect(yourMC).x + yourMC.getRect(yourMC).width, yourMC.getRect(yourMC).y + yourMC.getRect(yourMC).height));

  var alef: Number = point1.x; //x position of the object.
  var bet: Number = point1.y; //y position of the object.
  //var gimel: Number = point2.x - point1.x; //width of the object.
  //var daled: Number = point2.y - point1.y; //height of the object.

redClip.filters = [new GlowFilter()];
  var tweenY: Tween = new Tween(yourMC, "y", Regular.easeIn, alef, 392, 1, true);
  var tweenX: Tween = new Tween(yourMC, "x", Regular.easeIn, bet, 0, 1, true);
  //tweenY.stop();
  trace("hit");
  trace("x" + alef);
  trace("y" +  bet);


  } else {
  redClip.filters = [];
  //trace("miss");
  }
}
tweenY.stop();


trace(tweenY.stop);
stop();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I had to remove the listener and the X and Y got mixed up and now have been corrected.

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
        var yourMC: DisplayObject = blueClip;
        var point1: Point = yourMC.localToGlobal(new Point(yourMC.getRect(yourMC).x, yourMC.getRect(yourMC).y));
        var point2: Point = yourMC.localToGlobal(new Point(yourMC.getRect(yourMC).x + yourMC.getRect(yourMC).width, yourMC.getRect(yourMC).y + yourMC.getRect(yourMC).height));
        var alef: Number = point1.x; //x position of the object.
        var bet: Number = point1.y; //y position of the object.

        redClip.filters = [new GlowFilter()];

        var tweenXa: Tween = new Tween(blueClip, "x", Regular.easeIn, alef, 0, 1, true);
        var tweenYb: Tween = new Tween(blueClip, "y", Regular.easeIn, bet, 392, 1, true);

        //tweenY.stop();
        trace("hit");

        //trace("x" + alef);
        //trace("y" + bet);

    } else {
        redClip.filters = [];
        //trace("miss");
    }
}
```